# Cannot Connect to Azure Storage Account File Share

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I've been trying to figure this issue out for a few hours now.

I've created a Azure Storage Account and created a File Share with it. When I try to connect to it from any computer on any network the connection fails. I've tried with my Mac and Windows 10 computer.

I'm new to Azure so I'm not sure what data I can supply other then the error:

```
C:\Users\Charles>net use Z: \\name.file.core.windows.net\share /u:AZURE\name
```

> System error 53 has occurred.
>
> The network path was not found.

I've read all of Microsoft's documents on error 53, tried running through all the solutions; however, the documents on solutions and diagnosing seem to be really poorly written.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

**edit**

Comcast blocks port 445, which is likely causing my issue. Is there a workaround to this?

Thanks again.

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could mark it as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be several causes, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-53-error-67-or-error-87-when-you-mount-or-unmount-an-azure-file-share) to troubleshoot.

> Comcast blocks port 445, which is likely causing my issue. Is there a workaround to this?

If the issue caused by it, you could refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/15001032-allow-access-to-file-storage-configuration-to-use). It is a known issue, the **Microsoft Azure Storage Team** has given a workaround.

> One alternative to mounting the share on-premises over port 445 is **Azure File Sync**, which enables you to create a cache of an Azure file share on an on-premises Windows Server. Azure File Sync only sends data over the Azure Files HTTPS (using the File REST APIs).

For more details about Azure File Sync, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-sync-files-planning).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to switch to Azure Blobs instead of File Shares Microsoft provides a Fuse adapter here: 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse

Above project supported and works on Linux.

There are other similar implementations exist, this one is for Mac but doesn't look actively maintained:
https://github.com/cemheren/infinite